# Is caching npm ci in Azure Pipelines a bad idea?

Tags: node.js, npm, caching, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

Today I was looking up some information about caching in Azure Pipelines combined with installing NPM packages. We use `npm ci` in our pipelines which can take a while. Caching might speed it up (and introduce other risks) and I want to find out if caching `npm ci` is a good idea in a CI/CD pipeline or not because I find a lot of conflicting information about this.

## What benefit does caching have?

If I read the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#nodejsnpm), the following is said:

> Because `npm ci` deletes the `node_modules` folder to ensure that a consistent, repeatable set of modules is used, you should avoid caching `node_modules` when calling `npm ci`.

The thing that makes an `npm ci` so slow is that it has to retrieve all the `node_modules`.  But the only conclusion I can draw from that sentence above is that we should not cache `node_modules`. So *what is the point of enabling that cache task* for `npm ci` if the `node_modules` aren't cached? My assumption is that by not caching the `node_modules`, you lose the speed benefit which would have been the point of caching.

## Caching is dangerous, right?

`npm ci` provides a CLEAN install based on the `package-lock.json`. But if you add caching into the mix and retrieve some `node_modules` from the cache instead of the server, you create a risk of retrieving stale/outdated/wrong packages because cache invalidation is hard.

Based on this, caching and `npm ci` should never be used together, right?

## Conflicting information

The previous headers tell me that I shouldn't try to make `npm ci` faster by using a cache in azure pipelines. But if you use your favorite search engine and search for `azure pipelines cache npm`, you will find lots of resources telling you exactly how to do this. Including answers from Stack overflow:

- [Is there a way to speedup npm ci using cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55230628/3013479)
- [Caching NPM dependencies in Azure pipeline for in-built windows-latest image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59487604/3013479)
- https://packetlost.com/blog/2021/01/31/speed-up-azure-devops-pipelines-with-node_modules-caching/
- https://qxperts.io/caching-your-node-modules-in-azure-devops-2/

You can find many more. Why is there so much conflicting information?

## Finishing up

- Should you, or should you not, use the caching task in azure pipelines combined with `npm ci`. Please explain the reasons for your answer!
- If the consensus is **yes, you should, if you want to speed up your installs**: what are the benefits of using caching with `npm ci` if you don't cache the `node_modules`
- If the consensus is **no**, then what can we do to increase the speed of our installs?

Comment: MS docs: here are some scripts that use caching with `npm ci`. But remember, do not use caching with `npm ci`!

Comment: @ajbeaven That line in the MS docs isn't super clear, but their sample code shows caching the NPM cache (customized to be `./.npm`) so that packages can be installed from a local cache instead of over the network. It does this instead of caching node_modules because 1) node_modules gets erased by `npm ci` so the caching would be pointless, and 2) `npm ci` is best practice for a CI pipeline.

Answer (score 6):

The most important distinction to make is that caching your `node_modules` folder is different from caching `.npm`.

- `node_modules` is a folder created when running `npm i` or `npm ci`. It contains uncompressed packages, based on the dependencies as defined in `package-lock.json`.

When you run `npm ci` it throws away the `node_modules` folder, so it can build a new dependency tree based on your `package-lock` and do a clean install of all included packages.

On the other hand, `npm i` makes a new `package-lock` based on version descriptions in your `package.json`. Then it only updates packages in your `node_modules` folder with versions that changed.

Both commands first check the cache whether any requested versions already exist there for installation. If the package is not found in your cache, or the cached version is invalid, it will download a new version from the registry and update the cache.

- [`npm cache`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-cache) is what NPM uses internally to cache specific package data.

The default folder for the cache differs per OS, and the default for Linux/Mac (`~/.npm`) is not reachable in most CI environments.

This is why many resources [redefine the cache folder](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/config#cache) via `npm ci --cache .npm`. This lets `npm ci` know to look for the cache at **`./.npm`** instead, though any path inside the current workspace could be valid.

In order to preserve this custom folder between different CI pipelines, you can cache it again via Azure Pipelines (or whichever platform you're using).

Important: the cache you define in your pipeline must be invalidated and save a new version whenever `package-lock` changes, as that means `npm ci` will need to install new versions/packages and update its npm cache accordingly.

Note: you can also add the [`--prefer-offline`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-search#prefer-offline) flag in order to skip staleness checks on existing package versions to speed your pipeline up further.

---

**TL;DR**:

**Yes!** You should use `npm ci` and you can improve performance with caching. **BUT** you should *not* cache `node_modules`. Instead, npm has its own cache in a hidden system folder. Use the `--cache "custom/folder/path"` flag with `npm ci` to make sure the location of the npm cache is accessible and identical in every environment.

Comment: Could you please attempt to improve this answer by explicitly addressing some of the questions asked? They're really relevant questions in light of the confusing docs and it would help to provide clarity.